# How to convert Curl command to Powershell in Visual Studio

Tags: powershell, curl, post

I'm working in a project in Visual Studio (C#). I´ve been trying to convert this Curl command to PowerShell command, but can't achieve it.

```
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" --header "Content-Type: 
application/json" --data '{"path": "<subgroup_path>", "name": "<subgroup_name>", "parent_id": 
<parent_group_id> }' "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/groups/"
```

I've seen plenty examples and I've tried many of them without success.

My PowerShell command:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri http://<my_domain>/api/v4/groups/ -Headers '{"PRIVATE-TOKEN": 
"<my_token>"}' -ContentType "application/json" -Body '{"path": "<my_new_group>", "name": 
"<my_new_group>", "parent_id": 5 }'
```

And I get this error:

```
Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert the "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <my_token>" value of type 
"System.String" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary".
```

I also tried:

```
Invoke-WebRequest "http://<my_domain>/api/v4/groups" -Headers @{'accept' = 
'application/json'; 'PRIVATE-TOKEN' = '<my_token>'} -Method Post -Body 
@{"path": "<my_new_group>", "name": "<my_new_group>", "parent_id": 5 }
```

I've even changed this parameter in last command:

```
-Headers {'u'='<my_user_name>:<my_password>'}
```

I really need some advice or correction on how to launch this command. If anyone has any ideas or advice I would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As the error says: Don't use a string, but a dictionary, so instead of `'{"PRIVATE-TOKEN": "<my_token>"}'` use `@{"PRIVATE-TOKEN"= "<my_token>"}`.

Comment: I've been able to launch the command successfully from PowerShell. But as I do it from Visual Studio with "powershell.AddScript ()" I have errors due to the quotes apparently and I cannot get it to launch correctly this way. Any ideas Ocaso Protal?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with that. Ask a new question, make an [mre] and don't forget to add the error message.

Comment: Or better: Do a search, this might be already answered somewhere. And also look up "escape quotes c#"

Answer (score -3):

Fortunately, just changing what Ocaso Portal said I obtained the solution.

Comment: Perhaps @Ocaso should post his comment as an answer, and you can mark it as answered, to help readers looking for answered questions.

Comment: @WaitingForGuacamole Nah, that was just a kind of typo, I doubt it will be helpful for anyone. In fact I voted to close this question as "typo"